# How to install obfs4proxy on mac?

Tags: tor

## How to install obfs4proxy on mac?

`obfs4proxy` is a pluggable transport proxy for Tor, implementing obfs4.

`obfs4proxy` is a tool that attempts to circumvent censorship by transforming the Tor traffic between the client and the bridge.

This way censors, who usually monitor traffic between the client and the bridge, will see innocent-looking transformed traffic instead of the actual Tor traffic. `obfs4proxy` implements the obfuscation protocols obfs2, obfs3, ScrambleSuit (client only), meek (client only) and obfs4.

`obfs4proxy` is currently only supported as a managed pluggable transport spawned as a
helper process via the tor daemon.

Comment: I used to copy the obfs4proxy binary file from content of TorBrowser package file in Applications. But I don't think it is a decent way.

Answer (score 1):

Even better use HomeBrew for installation.

```
brew install obfs4proxy
```

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/obfs4proxy

Get the obsf4 bridges from https://bridges.torproject.org/options or send email to [bridges@torproject.org](http://mailto:bridges@torproject.org) with body `get transport obfs4`.

Edit the torrc file (`/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc`) and add the following

```
# Using Bridges, obsf4
UseBridges 1
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/local/bin/obfs4proxy managed

# send email to bridges@torproject.org with body `get transport obfs4` you can get new bridges.
# Or use https://bridges.torproject.org/options
# Paste the obsf4 bridges here and put Bridge in front of each.
Bridge obfs4 78.194.206.56.. B80190D0C0771298F04AE56L..... cert=61xl3nF07Ssg... iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 185.220.101.17.. 59F4CBDE79D51FEC12AC1F4304D006C97D4.. cert=p9L6... iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 185.220.101.17.. 59F4CBDE79D51FEC12AC1F4304D006C97D4.. cert=p9L6... iat-mode=2
```

Now restart the TOR service using

```
brew services restart tor
```

And it works fine.
[image]

To change the circuit run

```
brew services reload tor
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. I only changed paths to `/opt/homebrew/etc/tor/torrc` and `/opt/homebrew/bin/obfs4proxy`.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: If you have no GoLang environment. Install golang following some blogs such as: https://ahmadawais.com/install-go-lang-on-macos-with-homebrew/

step 2: `cd ~/Downloads && git clone https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-privacy-team/obfs4proxy`

step 3: `cd ~/Downloads/obfs4proxy` and follow the instructions to compile and install the `obfs4proxy` in https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-privacy-team/obfs4proxy